# How to control path alias in custom node form #validate function?

Tags: 7, forms, path-aliases

To change form values in code, I understand that the right way is to add a validate function with `hook_form_alter`, to append the function's name to the `#validate` array then use [form_set_value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_value/7).

When I inspect the form array at this point though, I cannot see a way to reliably determine the parents of the path value.

e.g. I have

```
$form_state['groups']['additional_settings'][4]['alias']
```

And I can only assume that the `4` index is not always going to be `4`; that it might be a different number if more modules are installed etc.

So how can I set the alias? (I also need to un-set pathauto's checkbox so it does not auto-generate a new path.) Am I doing it in the right place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the values submitted by the user in `$form_state['values]`. So you can just fetch the ones submitted alter them and them send them back to the form. And the path settings are located at `$form['path']`. `$form_state['groups']` is just a way of grouping form elements together.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Add our validate function to all node forms.
  $form['#validate'][] = 'MYMODULE_alter_node_path';
}

/**
 * Custom form validate function.
 */
function MYMODULE_alter_node_path($form, &$form_state) {
  // Fetch the path values submitted.
  $value = $form_state['values']['path'];
  // Do your changes to the path and unset pathauto checkbox.
  $value['alias'] = 'new-alias';
  $value['pathauto'] = FALSE;
  // Set the values in the form.
  form_set_value($form['path'], $value, $form_state);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Part of my problem was my [debugger config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302203/vdebug-xdebug-only-showing-first-32-elements-of-arrays) which meant I did not know of the existence of the `path` key in `$form`! But also I did not know you could do composite value setting in the way you have illustrated, which is interesting. I find it a little confusing, so I've gone with two calls to `form_set_value`, one to `$form['path']['alias']` and one to `$form['path']['pathauto']`. Many thanks